# обращение к классу

Tags: javascript, css

есть класс со стилями

css

```
.list a:hover{ 
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #f38104; 
}
```

и нужно что бы при загрузке окна `id="one"` задавался этот стиль.Застрял на 3й строке

js

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){                    
        var test = document.getElementById('one');
        test.style...;
```

Comment: Это не класс со стилями, а описание стилей для класса. Причем только для `<A>`, да вдобавок при наведении курсора. Следовательно - добавьте этот класс элементу, если этот элемент конечно `A`, если нет - то проще в самом css описать что данный стиль распространяется на `#one`

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){                    
    var test = document.getElementById('one');
    test.className = test.className + " list";
```

Comment: Обогнали меня на несколько секунд)

Comment: А никто не сказал, что этот элемент именно `<A>` и что назначение класса сработает :)

Comment: или так: `test.className += " list";`

Comment: не совсем ясно как элемент <a> получит свойства hover просто при загрузке страницы

Answer (score 1):

Что бы при загрузке у элемента был требуемый стиль проще всего не использовать JS, а указать данный элемент как селектор для нужного стиля в css. Т.е. надо просто поправить сам CSS примерно в таком ключе:

```
.list a:hover, #one:hover { 
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #f38104; 
}
```

Это соответственно в случае если стиль должен распространятся и на элементы с классом `list` и дополнительно на элемент с `id=one`

Comment: суть как раз в том , что данный элемент является ссылкой на пункт меню, и если мы заходим в тот же пункт меню , в таком случае <a> должно иметь свойства hover. К тому же таких <a> может быть и 10 с разными id и с селекторами получится не совсем

Comment: Стиль автоматически применяется ко всем тегам на странице отвечающим условиям селектора в данном стиле. В данном селекторе сказано, что он должен применяться кроме .list еще и к элементу с `id=one`, следовательно если при заходе в нужный пункт меню у требуемого элемента `<A>` должен быть `id=one` и данный стиль автоматически сработает

Comment: @ddeadlink тогда вам надо данный стиль сделать для какого либо класса, в вашем случае он задан для класса `list` и добавить именно класс элементу и если это происходит при загрузке страницы - то проще всего страницу сразу сформировать с правильными классами у элементов

Comment: @ddeadlink А просто так JS элементу назначить именно его поведение при hover невозможно в принципе. Это можно сделать только если самому обрабатывать события движения мыши для данного элемента и назначать ему нужные свойства когда мышь на него надвинулась

Comment: что - то не могу вьехать. <a> он же с id = "one" и он же test имеет свой класс к которому + класс "list" в теле функции .В итоге test имеет класс list. А сам же list a :hover будет работать только при наведении

Comment: @ddeadlink Я вот чего не понял, вам обязательно стили назначать динамически, при каких то действиях на странице, без загрузки этой страницы ? Просто в вашем примере вы это делаете разово при загрузке страницы ...

Comment: попробую объяснить полностью.  Есть сайдбар с меню (пунктов меню >5) Когда заходим в какой-то из пунктов меню, пункт меню должен "выделятся" на фоне других пунктов , т.е. так же как и при наведении мышью на тот же пункт. Как то так. И вышеупомянутые комментарии не наталкивают меня на решение

Comment: @ddeadlink При "Заходе" в пункт меню часть html содержащая это меню загружается с сервера вместе с остальной страницей заново. Или у в вас там какой нибудь ajax, который загружает только содержимое страницы, а меню заново не отдается ? Вы свой JS код предполагали отдавать с сервера в таком виде что бы он выделил "текущий" пункт меню, т.е. на сервере при отдаче страницы вы знаете какой пункт надо выделить ?

Comment: каждый пункт меню ведет на свою страницу,и на какую именно, я беру из get параметра  Значение ключа этого параметра возвращает соответствующая ф-я js. Тобишь кликая на 1й 2й и тд пункты меню мы знаем какой именно пункт нужно выделить

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33588/discussion-between-mike-and-ddeadlink).